# How to configure rest client in quarkus microprofile case

Tags: quarkus, microprofile

When using Quarkus microprofile as a rest client, how can I configure underlying HttpClient?
Like number of retries, connection pool size per host and so on?
Also is it possible to force client restart somehow (so connections pool will be restarted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... After a lot of digging, here is a solution I've found so far. It is not obvious apparently:

**To make it work in pure Java (no native)**

1. Under *resources/META-INF/services* directory add file named *org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.spi.RestClientBuilderListener* containing class name of your implementation of RestClientBuilderListener interface. For example my.test.MyBuilderListener. This will allow ServiceLocator to execute your listener
2. Refer a property you want to modify from ResteasyClientBuilder, for example to set your custom value to connectionTTL code will looks like this:

   ```
   public void onNewBuilder(RestClientBuilder builder) {
      log.info("Changing TTL for connections");
      builder.property("resteasy.connectionTTL", List.of(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
   }
   ```

Ie. add a *resteasy.* prefix to a property name

3. Profit

**Now native support:**
After steps above:

1. Set both MyBuildListener and ResteasyClientBuilder available for reflection by creating a file reflection-config.json:

```
    [
      {
        "name": "org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder",
        "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
        "allPublicConstructors": true,
        "allDeclaredMethods": true,
        "allPublicMethods": true,
        "allDeclaredFields": true,
        "allPublicFields": true
      }, {
        "name": "my.test.MyBuilderListener",
        "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
        "allPublicConstructors": true,
        "allDeclaredMethods": true,
        "allPublicMethods": true,
        "allDeclaredFields": true,
        "allPublicFields": true
       }
     ]
```

2. Add service registration file to resources. Create a file named resources-config.json with content

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "pattern": "META-INF/services/org\\.eclipse\\.microprofile\\.rest\\.client\\.spi\\.RestClientBuilderListener$"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. register both files in application.yaml:

```
quarkus:
  native:
    additional-build-args: -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json, -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json
```

4. Native profit

Have fun

Comment: The `ResteasyClientBuilder` and any implementation of `RestClientListener` should already be registered for native image and don't require their own `resources-config.json`. If that's not the case, then please raise an issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues

Comment: In addition, if you're using the programmatic API you don't need a listener, you can do:
`RestClientBuilder.property("resteasy.connectionTTL", List.of(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS));`

Comment: can you pls elaborate on the latest one?

Comment: If you're not doing `@Inject @RestClient MyClientInterface`, then you can use the `RestClientBuilder` to create the instance and set the property directly with the builder. See https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-1.2.1/microprofile-rest-client-1.2.1.html#programmatic_lookup for an example

Comment: thank you, Ken. I was trying to find any documentation on a Quarkus side how to do modifications to rest client and was not able to. Also I was not sure how deep I can go with microprofile modifications taking into consideration that there are some modifications done by Quarkus to make it work and my modifications can actually break smth. Anyways, I will try to use programmatic approach. But in general it would be goos to have an ability to modify RestClient similar way as we have for ObjectMapper

Answer (score 5):

https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0-RC2/microprofile-rest-client-2.0-RC2.html#_configuration_keys outlines the full set of configuration keys that can be used.

The ones you're looking for are:

```
{packageName}.{interfaceName}/mp-rest/connectTimeout
{packageName}.{interfaceName}/mp-rest/readTimeout
```

The `RestClientBuilder` also has methods for setting those properties if you're using the programmatic API instead of the CDI approach.

I'm not aware of any means of restarting the underlying HTTP client connection pool. What would be the use case for such a situation that doesn't require the whole application to be restarted?

Comment: Nope, i am looking for to set connectionTTL

Comment: @KonstantinKulagin  I don’t know what you mean with restarts. But you can add/combine Microprofile Fault on your Rest client, like retries and fallbacks. Check Ken’s link and scroll down to below dor examples.