# Quarkus rest client: how to combine leveled rest client config in YAML config

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am using Quarkus rest client and I already have congis in YAML like:

```yaml
quarkus:
  rest-client:
    my-api:
      url: ${api.url}
      scope: javax.inject.Singleton
      connection-pool-size: 20
```

Now I want to add `mp-rest/readTimeout` and `mp-rest/connectTimeout` as per [How to configure rest client in quarkus microprofile case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795633/how-to-configure-rest-client-in-quarkus-microprofile-case)

How should I put them? Should camel case be converted to hyphen cased?

Like this?

```yaml
quarkus:
  rest-client:
    my-api:
      url: ${api.url}
      scope: javax.inject.Singleton
      connection-pool-size: 20
      mp-rest/readTimeout: 5000
      mp-rest/connectTimeout: 5000
```

or:

```yaml
quarkus:
  rest-client:
    my-api:
      url: ${api.url}
      scope: javax.inject.Singleton
      connection-pool-size: 20
      mp-rest: 
        read-timeout: 5000
        connect-timeout: 5000
```

BTW why YAML format is not mentioned in [doc](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-2.0.html#mpconfig)? I don't know other people but I always prefer YAML and I don't like the doc only preferring `.properties` format, also I was searching in the Github repo but found no example in YAML. The conversion from properties format to YAML, in many cases, is not trivial.

For me, what is ideal is:

- when writing tests, externalizing 2 formats of config files and write 2 set of tests
- providing examples in 2 formats like what Maven repository did:
  [image]

Comment: AFAIK the name of the property is `/mp-rest/url` so `/mp-rest/readTimeout: 5000` should be the right way

Comment: Yes I was wrong by missing the first "/". Sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the `/mp-rest` at all.

You can just use:

```
quarkus:
  rest-client:
    my-api:
      url: ${api.url}
      scope: javax.inject.Singleton
      connection-pool-size: 20
      read-timeout: 5000
      connect-timeout: 5000
```

See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-rest-client-config_quarkus-rest-client-config-rest-client-config) for more details

Comment: OK this is the right place, thanks! You are part of the Quarkus core team, that's why..

Comment: Indeed that is true :)