# Configure programmatically built RestClient with connection pool, as URL is dynamic

Tags: quarkus-rest-client

[How to configure rest client in quarkus microprofile case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795633/how-to-configure-rest-client-in-quarkus-microprofile-case)

I have seen this related but in my case is different, that URL is put into config and picked up dynamically, so I need to do something like: https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-rest-client/blob/main/spec/src/main/asciidoc/programmatic_lookup.asciidoc

But I wonder what is the pool in this dynamically built client. Only one thread? And then closed and never reused? Can I reuse it with a pool?